# Total number of combinations for pairing from two different sets

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Assume we have two sets of numbers {1, 2, 3} and  {4,5,6}. My aim is to pair two numbers together from the two different sets such as

{1} with {4}

{2} with {5}

{3} with {6}

another pairing would be

{1} with {5}

{2} with {6}

{3} with {4}

Rule is no two numbers from same set can be paired with same number from the second set.

What is the total number of combinations that I can have?

How can I generalize this result, more precisely assume the two sets have $N$ numbers what is the total number of combinations that can be considered.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you learned the definition of a permutation in the sense of functions?  In that a permutation is a bijective function from a set to itself?  Without loss of generality, your two sets can both be $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "pairing" is an injective function from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{4,5,6\}$.
For the image of $1$ you have $3$ choices. There are two choices left for the image of $2$, and one choice for the image of $3$. The conclusion comes from the product rule: there are $1\times 2\times 3 = 6$ injective functions.

Comment: so general answer for any $N$ would be $N!$

Comment: @Henry: The number of injective functions from a set $X$ with $n$ elements to a set $Y$ with $m$ elements $(m\geqslant n)$ is $m(m-1)\dots (m-n+1)$. If $n = m$, there are $n!$ injective functions.