# How can I find replace exhaustive search to find my optimal solution?

Tags: combinatorics

Assume I have two sets each of cardinality $N$. My first goal is to pair the two sets such that no element in set 1 is paired twice with any element of set two! Thanks to the answer provided to the question I asked here: [Total number of combinations for pairing from two different sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483581/total-number-of-combinations-for-pairing-from-two-different-sets) there are $N!$ possible combinations.

Lets stick to set 1 being {1,2,3} and set 2 being {4,5,6}. Then the total number of pairing is 6. Let say that we have decided to pair as follows:

1---4

2---5

3---6

A pairing such as the one that I chose above in my problem would result a matrix of 9 entries (a bit tricky, please bear with me!)

$M= \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13} \\
    x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23} \\
    x_{31}       & x_{32} & x_{23} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

The reason I have 9 entries which have resulted from my pairing is because $x_{11}$ would be cost (quantity) representing an edge connecting node (1-4) while $x_{21}$ represents a cost of edge connecting (1-5) and $x_{31}$ would be for (1-6) and so on for (2-4) (2-5) (2-6) (3-4) (3-5) (3-6). Another pairing would give me different values of the 9 entries.

If the number of elements in the two sets were $N= 4$, then a particular pairing would result in matrix with 16 entries.

My goal is to maximize

$$ \text {determinant} ( {\bf I} + M)$$

**Problem**

Assume I am looking for THE ONE and ONLY COMBINATION that can maximize a certain this determinant that is ofcourse a function of the combination I choose.

Would exhaustive search be the only way for me to look after my optimal combination of pairs?

I am looking for references of intelligent methods to combat this exhaustive search..

thanks

Comment: The method would depend very much on the quantity that you are trying to maximize. Why don't you include it in the question?

Comment: thanks, ill edit accordingly.

Comment: @Aravind can you please let me know if now its more clear..

Comment: How are you calculating the costs of these edges?

Comment: pairing 1 with 4 and 2 with 5 and 3 with 6, has given me $x_{11}= 5, x_{22}= 6, x_{33}= 9$ while a pairing 1 with 5 and 2 with 6 while 3 with 4 gives $x_{11}= 1, x_{22}= 1, x_{33}= 1$, therefore I choose the first pairing because it gives the three largest possible values... The rest of the 6 entires from the 9 are values that have resulted from my pairing...